# How to do a notification in an If statement but continue a While loop in Python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm using psutil and Python to notify me when I'm on battery power or AC power.  I have a while loop that continuously checks for battery power.  I want it to notify me when we're on battery power, but only once.  If I declare the variable power_notification = 0 anywhere, it will reset it to 0 when the while loop runs again.  How do I keep the count so it only notifies me once until we're back on AC?  I get no errors but it continuously print that's we're on battery power.

```py
import psutil

power_good = True

def check_power_status():
    power_notification = 0
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    plugged_in = battery.power_plugged
    percent = str(battery.percent)

    if not plugged_in:
        if power_notification == 0:
            plugged_in = "We are on battery power."
            print(plugged_in + "\n" + "You have " + percent + "% of your battery remaining.")
            power_notification = 1
        else:
            power_good = False
            return power_good
    else:
        power_good = True
        return power_good

while power_good:
    check_power_status()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep it running as `daemon` so `while` should have `True` all the time. So I can't see any reason for using `power_good`.

The `power_notification` should be outside the function to maintain its value.

```
import psutil

power_notification = 0

def check_power_status():
    global power_notification
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    plugged_in = battery.power_plugged
    percent = str(battery.percent)

    if not plugged_in:
        if power_notification == 0:
            plugged_in = "We are on battery power."
            print(plugged_in + "\n" + "You have " + percent + "% of your battery remaining.")
            power_notification = 1
    #AC plugged_in 
    else:
        power_notification = 0

while True:
    check_power_status()
```

Comment: I feel like this is the correct answer but the power_notification == 0 is getting an Unresolved reference error.  It's not finding it as a global variable.

Comment: I don't know if this is unique to PyCharm, but I followed your answer but had to add "global power_notification" in the power status function.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are right, to change global variable inside a function you should mention first that it is global. otherwise, it will treat it as a local variable. [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword#introduction)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only things you need to do is make **power_notification** global and reset it to 0 when the power is good:

```
import psutil

power_good = True
power_notification = 0

def check_power_status():
    battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
    plugged_in = battery.power_plugged
    percent = str(battery.percent)

    if not plugged_in:
        if power_notification == 0:
            plugged_in = "We are on battery power."
            print(plugged_in + "\n" + "You have " + percent + "% of your battery remaining.")
            power_notification = 1
        else:
            power_good = False
            return power_good
    else:
        power_good = True
        power_notification = 0
        return power_good

while power_good:
    check_power_status()
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: When I tried this code, the power_notification isn't recognized in the if power_notification loop.  Pycharm yells at me and says it's an unresolved reference.

Comment: I seem to be unable to reproduce that error. Is this your full code?

Comment: I don't know if this is unique to PyCharm, but I followed the answer below this, which is similar to your answer and had to add "global power_notification" in the power status function and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yea the answers were similar but Mohammed cleaned up the code a bit more. Enjoy the rest of your project!

Comment: thanks!  Now, I'm going to spend some time figuring out to detect the changing states.  So, if I keep plugging in and unplugging my laptop, it still only tells me once.

Comment: Really? Are you using Mohammeds code? It's working for me. Try updating pip and reinstalling psutil.